# HTML button refreshes in SharePoint Hosted App

Tags: app

I have an HTML button in my SharePoint hosted app like this:

```
<input type="button" id="btnSubmit" value="Test"/>
```

and I tried

```
<button id="btnSubmit">Test </button>
```

But it is always refreshing until I remove all the code from SharePoint and leave it as regular HTML page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your buttons are in a SharePoint FORM, so when you add a button the click event is bubbling up to the FORM, and the FORM is submitted.

You have to add JavaScript code to stop that from happing with

```
event.stopPropagation();
```

or

```
event.preventDefault();
```

See:
https://codeplanet.io/preventdefault-vs-stoppropagation-vs-stopimmediatepropagation/

Comment: thanks Danny, but doesn't this happen only with <button> not with <input> ?

Comment: Button is default of type submit, use `type="button"` as in your first example and you will be fine, not need for the JS

Comment: thanks eirkib, I noticed that when I remove the sharepoint content place holders and just leave the <web part pages> the refresh goes away, but when I do that on regular page of sp, it's back. any idea?

Comment: Check the resulting markup, if the `<button>` resides inside a `<form>` it will trigger form submit on click